# React Native Modal Blinking/Re-initializing Issue on Skill Details Input Field Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am encountering a peculiar issue in my React Native application. I have implemented a modal for adding and editing skills. However, whenever I make changes in the skill details input fields within the modal, the modal blinks or seems to get re-initialized.

Here's a simplified description of my code structure:

```
<ModalPopup visible={visible1}>
          <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <View style={Styles.header}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setVisible1(false)}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../../../../assets/images/x-image.png')}
                  style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <ScrollView>
            <View>
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: "black" }}>Skill:</Text>
              <Dropdown
                //  containerStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red' }}
                //  dropdownStyle={{backgroundColor:"black", color: 'black' }}
                selectedTextStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
                itemTextStyle={{ color: "black" }}
                style={[Styles.dropdown, isSkillFocus2 && { borderColor: 'blue', color: "black" }]}
                placeholderStyle={Styles.placeholderStyle}
                // selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
                // inputSearchStyle={Styles.inputSearchStyle}
                iconStyle={Styles.iconStyle}

                data={skillrows}
                search
                maxHeight={300}
                width={300}
                labelField="label"
                valueField="value"
                placeholder={!isSkillFocus2 ? 'Select Skill to edit' : '...'}
                searchPlaceholder="Search..."
                value={skillvalue2}

                // onFocus={() => setIsSkillFocus2(true)}
                // onBlur={() => setIsSkillFocus2(false)}
                onChange={item => {
                  setSkillValue2(item.value);
                  setIsSkillFocus2(false);
                }}
              />
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: "black" }}>Details:</Text>
              <TextInput style={Styles.Textcontainer} value={details} name="Details" control={control} onChangeText={(value)=> setDetails(value)} />
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: "black" }}>Field:</Text>
              <TextInput style={Styles.Textcontainer} value={Field} name="Field" control={control} editable={false} />
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: "black" }}>Skill Rating:</Text>
              <Dropdown
                //  containerStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red' }}
                //  dropdownStyle={{backgroundColor:"black", color: 'black' }}
                selectedTextStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
                itemTextStyle={{ color: "black" }}
                style={[Styles.dropdown, isratingFocus2 && { borderColor: 'blue', color: "black" }]}
                placeholderStyle={Styles.placeholderStyle}
                // selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
                // inputSearchStyle={Styles.inputSearchStyle}
                iconStyle={Styles.iconStyle}

                data={skillRating}
                search
                maxHeight={300}
                width={300}
                labelField="label"
                valueField="value"
                placeholder={!isratingFocus2 ? 'Select Rating' : '...'}
                searchPlaceholder="Search..."
                value={ratingvalue2}

                // onFocus={() => setIsRatingFocus2(true)}
                // onBlur={() => setIsRatingFocus2(false)}
                onChange={item => {
                  setRatingValue2(item.value);
                  setIsRatingFocus2(false);
                }}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity style={[Styles.container]} onPress={handleSubmit(EditSkill)} >
                <Text style={[Styles.text]} >Save</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: "center", margin: 5 }} onPress={cancelModalPress2}>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>Cancel</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {loading1 && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />}
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </ModalPopup>
```

I have attempted to debug the issue but haven't been able to identify the root cause. I suspect it might be related to the re-rendering of the modal or state management, but I'm not sure.

Could anyone please provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance in troubleshooting and fixing this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey, can you describe what you mean by editing ? does entering text for example also cause the flickering ?